# find in mongoDB for nested documents?

Tags: mongodb

this is a mongoDB structure:

**-users**

**--articles**

**---tags**

```
**Collection**
user:
[
    {  
        _id : ID,
        username : "u1",
        articles:
        [
            {_id : ID,title:"",url: "",tags:["a", "b", "c"]},
            {_id : ID,title:"",url: "",tags:["a1", "b1", "c3"]},
            ...
        ]
    },
    {  
        _id : ID,
        username : "u2",
        articles:
        [
            {title:"",url: "",tags:["a3", "b3", "c3"]},
            {title:"",url: "",tags:["a4", "b4", "c3"]},
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

How can get all articles with "c3" tags for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your collection contains documents which contain articles which contain tags:

```
db.collection.find({articles.tags: "c3"}, {articles: 1})
```